# Find and track javascript code that modified the DOM

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom, drupal

There is a javascript event that is modifying a search box but since I was not the original developer, I have no clue where it was written. I know it's Javascript because when I disabled Javascript in the browser it stopped working. But this is the Drupal CMS with tonnes of .js files and this person followed none of the standard places for putting .js files. How do I track down where the snippet of code that is causing the trouble is located?

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome Inspector tool can do that.

An answer you're going to want to read is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7054733 .